# Cordova SalesforceSDK - Icons & splash screens not working

Tags: sfdcmobilesdk-android, cordova, phonegap, salesforce-sdk-hybrid

I am developing a hybrid android mobile application using Phonegap/Cordova and Salesforce mobile SDK. I am trying to change the icon and splash screen but it is not working as expected.

Reference Link: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/images.html

I have update my `config.xml` like below,

```
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000"/>
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />

        <icon src="icons/icon-ldpi.png" density="ldpi" />
        <icon src="icons/icon-mdpi.png" density="mdpi" />
        <icon src="icons/icon-hdpi.png" density="hdpi" />
        <icon src="icons/icon-xhdpi.png" density="xhdpi" />

        <splash src="icons/screen-land-hdpi.png" density="land-hdpi"/>
        <splash src="icons/screen-land-ldpi.png" density="land-ldpi"/>
        <splash src="icons/screen-land-mdpi.png" density="land-mdpi"/>
        <splash src="icons/screen-land-xhdpi.png" density="land-xhdpi"/>

        <splash src="icons/screen-port-hdpi.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
        <splash src="icons/screen-port-ldpi.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
        <splash src="icons/screen-port-mdpi.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
        <splash src="icons/screen-port-xhdpi.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
    </platform>
```

When I emulate the application, the config.xml (in platforms/android/res/) is updating accordingly. But nothing seems to be working and I still see Salesforce icon which looks like below,

[image]

Any idea why it is not working?

Answer (score 1):

I have solution about icon. You have to rename your icon image as 'sf__icon.png' and paste that file to all the resource folders. Then just run your project. The icon image will be changed.